# Jquery lack of similarity between insertBefore() & insertAfter()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am probably not the first to notice that when using insertBefore & insertAfter, the methods require different syntax. I was hoping someone could explain why.

Here is my (functional!) code:

```
/* change the order of form elements */
function sendup(row) {

// needs to move two up.  Step up to the containing span MT
var prevRow = $(row).prevAll('#checkboxSelect').first().get(0);

    if(prevRow) {
        row.parentNode.insertBefore(row, prevRow);
    }
}

function senddown(row) {
$('#checkboxSelect').insertAfter()
// Step up to the containing span MT
var nextRow = $(row).nextAll('#checkboxSelect').first().get(0);

    if(nextRow) {
        $( row ).insertAfter( nextRow );
    }
}
```

HTML/PHP loop to create checkbox list (if relevant):

```
<span id="checkboxSelect">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_group[]" id="$field" value="$field">$field<span style="float:right;"><a onclick="sendup(this.parentNode.parentNode)"><img src="icon_uparrow.png"></a>&nbsp;<a onclick="senddown(this.parentNode.parentNode)"><img src="icon_downarrow.png" border="0"></a></span><br>
</span>
```

Making this Jquery functional was painful because of this lack of similarity.

Comment: [$.fn.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) and [$.fn.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) have very similar syntax, the problem is that you're using the native DOM [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore), which does have different parameter order.

Answer (score 2):

Actually [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) have the same signature in jQuery. Although you're using the pure js [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore), which is not a jQuery function.